# PowerBI Gantt Chart

Tags: powerbi, parent

I have a data table with 6 columns - (a) Event ID, (b) Region, (c) Organisation Type, (d) Priority Level, (e) Start Date, and (f) End Date. As you would expect for a Gantt Chart, (e) and (f) are used as the horizontal bar charts.

I have issues with the vertical axis (using PowerBI's own version of Gantt Chart). Currently, my Gantt Chart has the following rows (on the left of the gantt chart) - (c) Organisation Type (parent node), drilled down to (a) Event ID. Event ID rows are unique. There are 40 of them. (d) Priority Level is the legend (colour of the bars).

Now I want to add (b) Region as the (grand)parent node to BEFORE the (c) Organisation Type, followed by (a) Event ID. So Region > Organisation Type > Event ID. (currently I can only choose Region OR Organisation Type, and then Event ID. I can't choose both). Does PowerBI only allow 1 parent level?